# Determine if flags were actually passed in (sub)command invocation in golang's cobra/viper

Tags: go, flags, viper-go, cobra

I have a `cobra` command

```
var mycommandCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "mycommand",
    PersistentPreRunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
        viper.BindPFlags(cmd.Flags())
```

and a subcommand

```
var mysubcommandCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "mysubcommand",
    Args:  cobra.ExactArgs(1),
    RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
        viper.BindPFlags(cmd.Flags())
```

which I of course bind together

```
mycommandCmd.AddCommand(mysubcommandCmd)
```

I also have some flags for both of them

```
mycommandCmd.PersistentFlags().BoolP("foo", "", true, "Whether to foo")
mysubcommandCmd.Flags().BoolP("foobar", "", true,  "Whether to foobar")
```

My question is the following:

Assuming the end `go` binary is named `prog`, is there a (`cobra` / `viper`) built in way of checking of whether any flags were actually passed during subcommand invocation?

i.e. how can I programmatically distinguish between this

```
prog mycommand mysubcommand --foobar
```

and this

```
prog mycommand mysubcommand
```

Checking against the default flag values will not work of course (and does not scale against the flag number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
isSet:=cmd.Flags().Lookup("foobar").Changed
```

That should return if the flag was set, or if the default value was used.

Comment: so in order for me to check say if NONE of them was actually set, this has to be done for all flags, one by one, right?

Comment: For bools, yes. For strings, you can give an empty default and check if it is empty.